# Dispatching multiple conditional actions

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to design an ngrx Effect that will look through the list of objects. If an id is in this list it needs to update the reducer with the new Id and navigate to a new route.

If an id is not in the list it just needs to navigate to a new route. This conditional path works. The NavigateToNewApp(newPath) will successfully route to a new path.

The return of(concatMap), which needs to fire two actions - SetThingIdSuccess and NavigateToNewInternalApp does not work. I get: `UserEffects.setAppContext" dispatched an invalid action: {"_isScalar":true}`. If I take off the of, it is simply undefined.

Is there a better way to architect this? What is the best way to send multiple effects from a conditional statement in ngrx?

```
@Effect()
setAppContext = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(UserActionTypes.DoAPermittedThing),
  withLatestFrom(
    this.store$.select(getPermittedThingIDs),
    this.store$.select(getPermittedThings)
  ),
  map(([thingID, permittedThingIDs, permittedThings]) => {
    if (permittedThingIDs.find(id => (thingID as any).payload === id) < 0) {
      const newPath = permittedThings[0].Path;
      return new NavigateToNewApp(newPath);
    }
    return of(
      concatMap(() => {
        const currentId = (thingID as any).payload as number;
        return [new SetThingIdSuccess(currentId), new NavigateToNewInternalApp()];
      })
  })
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Austin wrote about this in [Dispatching Multiple Actions from NGRX Effects](https://medium.com/@amcdnl/dispatching-multiple-actions-from-ngrx-effects-c1447ceb6b22)

> How do we solve this? Lets break out switchMap to return a new
>   observable array with multiple actions!

```
@Effect() save = this.update$.pipe(
   map(action => action.payload),
   switchMap(payload => this.myService.save(payload)),
   switchMap(res => [
       new Notification('save success'),
       new SaveSuccess(res)
   ])
);
```

In your case I think you should not be using `map`, but rather `concatMap` and always return an array with your actions.

Comment: Thanks. Nice ngx-testing-library by the way!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that in this effect you return the `SetThingIdSuccess` action if it needs to be set, and then create a new effect for `SetThingIdSuccess` that returns `NavigateToNewInternalApp`. It doesn't have to happen within the same effect and navigating is a side effect of the success action so it makes sense to break it out.